# Search facility with SQL using PhP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a search facility that searches through 2 different columns in two different tables, so if either name from hotel table matches or guest_id from guest table, output whatever is in while loop. However one of them works:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM hotel
                   INNER JOIN booking
                    ON hotel.hotel_id=booking.hotel_id
                    INNER JOIN guest
                    ON guest.guest_id=booking.guest_id
                    WHERE name LIKE :search_term");
```

However this one doesn't work it gives me an empty result

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM guest
                       INNER JOIN booking
                       ON guest.guest_id=booking.guest_id
                       INNER JOIN hotel
                       On booking.hotel_id=hotel.hotel_id
                       WHERE guest_id LIKE :search_term");
$stmt->bindValue(':search_term','%'.$search_term. '%');
```

My full code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Database</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- This is linking style sheet (css)into this HTML page-->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
    <form action = "index.php" method="get">
        <input type = "submit" name = "mainpage" value = "Main Page" class = "submitbut" id = "but1" />
    </form>
</div>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type = "text" name = "search" id = "searching" />
    <input type = "submit" name = "data_submit" value = "Search" id = "scan" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['mainpage'])){
    header("Location:mainpage.php");
exit;
}
if (isset($_POST["data_submit"])){
$search_term = $_POST['search'];
$conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1358595', 
    'root'
    );
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM hotel
                       INNER JOIN booking
                        ON hotel.hotel_id=booking.hotel_id
                        INNER JOIN guest
                        ON guest.guest_id=booking.guest_id
                        WHERE name LIKE :search_term");
$stmt->bindValue(':search_term','%'.$search_term. '%');
$stmt->execute();
echo
"<table><tr>  
<th>Results</th>
</tr>";
while($hotel = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo
"<tr>"."<td>"."<a href='details.php?name=".$hotel['name']."'>".$hotel['name']."</a>"."</td>"."</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM guest
                       INNER JOIN booking
                       ON guest.guest_id=booking.guest_id
                       INNER JOIN hotel
                       On booking.hotel_id=hotel.hotel_id
                       WHERE guest_id LIKE :search_term");
$stmt->bindValue(':search_term','%'.$search_term. '%');
$stmt->execute();
echo
"<table><tr>  
<th>Results</th>
</tr>";
while($hotel = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo
"<tr>"."<td>"."<a href='details.php?name=".$hotel['first_name']."'>".$hotel['last_name']."</a>"."</td>"."</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
$conn = NULL;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turn on error_reporting and you can't add % like that '%'.$search_term. '%' you need to do it before the bind, not in it..

Comment: I think you can with `bindValue` but not `bindParam` (since that requires the variable be passed by reference) ... but I'd have to check to be certain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have got an issue with WHERE clause. You are not defining from which table column guest_id is compared. `guest_id` should be replaced with `guest.guest_id` i believe.

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM guest
                       INNER JOIN booking
                       ON guest.guest_id=booking.guest_id
                       INNER JOIN hotel
                       On booking.hotel_id=hotel.hotel_id
                       WHERE guest.guest_id LIKE :search_term");
$stmt->bindValue(':search_term','%'.$search_term. '%');
```

EDIT:

Also, the search part could be replaced with:

```
... '...WHERE guest.guest_id LIKE "%":search_term"%"');
    $stmt->bindValue(':search_term', $search_term);
```

You would need to use single quotes for the query though.

Comment: Also, check other queries, as I can see that you are doing the same thing with SELECT * FROM hotel
                       INNER JOIN booking ....

Comment: The other query works fine actually it was only this one causing me trouble, now I need to sort out my results on another page as it's not working right ;/

Comment: basically I get the same output on another page no matter what i put

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MATCH AGAINST : [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

```
SELECT * FROM hotel
    INNER JOIN booking
      ON hotel.hotel_id=booking.hotel_id
    INNER JOIN guest
       ON guest.guest_id=booking.guest_id
WHERE MATCH (col1, col2)
    AGAINST ('+keyword1' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that this should have a `FULLTEXT` index across the searchable fields.